# Trying to receive information from a JSON file and result is NULL

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get data from a .json file and the result seems to be null.

I have been trying this and it has worked before with the exact same code and it worked perfectly

```
let ItemList = "./ItemList.json"
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', ItemList)
request.responseType = "json"
request.send()
request.onload = function () {
  const Items = request.response
  console.log(Items[0])
}
```

My questions are why is it the error `Cannot read property '0' of null at XMLHttpRequest.request.onload`  and how can I fix it,

And my second question is, what is a better way to do this.

I have tried other things like referencing it further in such as `console.log(Items.Test.TestCategory.TestProduct)` and that still didn't work

My Json File

```
{
  "AnotherTestProduct":[1,2], //this is what I'm trying to get
  "Test": {
    "TestCategory":{
      "TestProduct": [0, "TestProduct", 5, 10, 0],//[Id, Name, Customer price, Stock price, inStock]
    }
  },
  "Food": {
    "Candy": {
      "Chocolate-Bar": [0,""]
    }

    
  }
}
```

My code that worked perfectly

```
 let PeopleNames = "./PeopleNames.json"
  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', PeopleNames)
  request.responseType = 'json';
  request.send();
  request.onload = function () {
    const Names = request.response;
    function Genders(Gender) {
      if (Gender === 0)
        return Names.firstNamesF[getRandomInt(999)] + " " +
          Names.lastNames[getRandomInt(986)]

      else if (Gender === 1) {
        return Names.firstNamesM[getRandomInt(999)] + " " +
          Names.lastNames[getRandomInt(986)]
      }
    }
    Generator = Genders(getRandomInt(2));
    function getRandomInt(max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
    }
    var div = document.getElementById("name")
    div.innerHTML = Generator
  }
```

The Json that worked basically went

```
"firstNamesF": ["Emma", + 989 more strings]
"firstNamesM": ["Bob", + 989 more strings]
"lastNames": ["Wilson" + 970 more strings]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
request.onload = function () {
  const Items = request.response
  console.log(Items[0])
}
```

You are trying to print an **array** value of your JSON **object**

```
request.onload = function () {
  const Items = request.response;
  const myFirstKey = Object.keys(Items)[0];
  console.log(Items[myFirstKey])
}
```

Your JSON:

> {
> "AnotherTestProduct":[1,2], //this is what I'm trying to get

Comment: The result of this was nothing. Nothing was added to the console.

The weird thing though is that it worked one time in the code before, does that have anything to do with it.

Comment: You should print Object.keys(Items), if your JSON is what you pasted, Items.Test, Items.Food and Item.AnotherTestProduct should give you the values expected. It's weird thought that the code works with what you pasted width console.log(Items[0]); Maybe log `typeof Items`, the only explanation I see is that the result is sent with no JSON header and interpreted as string

Comment: It is an object, and it is really weird that it had once worked perfectly before.

Comment: Did you make sure that the file exist? If you are using windows I wouldn't reference a path location in that way.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname

Comment: path = path.join(_dirname, 'myFile.json')

Comment: I am not using node.js sadly, i am just using HTML5, JS, and CSS

Comment: Ok, so no nodeJS means local access to file.Are SURE that is not a CORS error telling that the local files (like in your path) are not accessible? Because if that's the case you'll have many more errors if you don't disable security on the webbrowser or serve the files from a local server

Comment: I think that it was accessible because I could do ```console.log(typeof Items)```

Comment: Welcome to JavaScript, where typeof null === "object'...
Yeah I know, it's weird, that's just javascript

Comment: Ok weird, but path.join(_dirname, url) doesn't seem to work

Comment: path and __dirname are NodeJS functions/variables, it wont work on frontEnd scripts. Please go to the webDev tools (ctrl+shift+I or F12) and check the console and the network tab (and reload the page while having the devTools open)

Comment: Do you know if the website relp.it would have it, because with my damn chromebook I am unable to do that

Comment: The only thing I can help you with on that particular code is to add request.onerror = (error) => { console.log(error); }. Pimp it a bit to recognize it. If the function runs and gives you and error, your file is not loaded and you can stop this headache because it's most certainly CORS that is at fault

Comment: Ah good to know its not my fault, I will now close this question

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is not valid. Invalid JSON will not parse.  You can check it here:

https://jsonlint.com/

```
  "TestProduct": [0, "TestProduct", 5, 10, 0],
```

has an extraneous comma at the end, should be

```
  "TestProduct": [0, "TestProduct", 5, 10, 0]
```

Comment: I went in and fixed that and it still says null

Comment: When I remove that comma and remove the comments, I am able to get and parse that JSON. The error you're getting suggests that you are not receiving the JSON file at all, like a 404 error. Are you sure it's getting loaded?

Comment: Yes, because I can do ```console.log(typeof Items)``` and it equals an ```object```

Answer (score 1):

One reason you may receive an error for one file and not another is likely due to the size. Bigger the size the longer it takes to process. If you increase the size of people.json do you get the same error?

If you are new to javascript it may sound weird but JS doesn't wait on code before executing the next line. So even though in the code you said open the file before onload, JS will try to onload before open finishes.

If you increase the size of people.json and you still get an error try wrapping the XHR request in a promise function.

```
const getData = (uri) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('get', uri, true);
        xhr.responseType = 'document';
        xhr.onload = () => {
            const status = xhr.status;
            if (status == 200) {
                // complete your function
                // Think about resolve as return.
                // It's not the same but it is.
                resolve(SOMETHING)
            } else {
                reject(status);
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    });
}
```

Then when you need to get something do this

`const uri = './ItemList.json'`

```
const getProducts = async (uri) => {

   const data = await getData(uri);
   // Do something here
}
```

Comment: The people.json is very very large, but it doesn't have an error, and the Items had worked before with my code, it just isn't working now

Comment: Okay, does people still work? If so then its probably something to do with the path aka 404 error. If it's also not working, please use a promise function.

Comment: I am trying the promise function right now, I've never used them so its taking some time. And yes people does still work

Comment: I got the error ```SOMETHING is not defined
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload``` and I don't know what to put there

Comment: If people still works, then its probably that the file doesn't exist or it can't find the path. Use path.join(_dirname, ItemList.json)

Comment: You would resolve the results os in your case request.response

Comment: I am not using nodejs, only HTML5, JS, and CSS with repl.it

Comment: Node.js was derived from the chrome runtime. Anything you can do inside of node should carry over to the browser. You can share your repl.it and ill take a look there. Do not respond to this comment, start a chat as the tread is very long.